# How to extend Facebook access token without an app?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So i imported the Facebook module into python to use it for some personal scripts that i want to create and eventually link this to Arduino. So let's say i have something like this:

```
import facebook
import codecs

token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")

friend_list = [friend['name'].encode('utf-8') for friend in friends['data']]

for i in friend_list:
  print i.decode('utf-8')
```

This works, however the token that i am generating [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) expires after one hour. I see that the GraphAPI class has some methods for extending access tokens but they need 'app_id' and 'app_secret' as parameters. What is this all about? 
So my question is, how can i extend this token without a Facebook app? Or how can i do something like posted above without a token, based only on user name and password for example?

Thanks!

Comment: @macdonjo No, but I abandoned that project a while ago. I think you actually can't do it without a Facebook app :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I am posting in case it is helpful to anyone else since I was just struggling with something similar.

You need a app_id & app_secret to extend the expiration.

If you do have a fb app and want to extend the user token in python, you can extended it to 60 day expiry using the GraphAPI.extend_access_token() method.

See: [How to extend my facebook graph API token in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594829/how-to-extend-my-facebook-graph-api-token-in-python)