# How to extend my facebook graph API token in python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I´m currently mining facebook using python. Until now, I´m getting an access token for graph API version 1.0(I need it to be 1.0) via this website:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me&version=v1.0

but the token I get on this site expires in about 1 hour, so how can I extend this token in python? I already saw how to in php, but, unfotunately, I have to stick with only python for my project

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending has this as one of the cases it explains - what specifically isn't working for you when you try to extend the token validity?

Comment: how do I extend the token validity? By now I was obtaining a new token manually every time the token expired

Comment: The document i linked explains how to extend a token you already have so that it won't expire for ~60 days

Comment: how do I do this GET by using python? GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}

Answer (score 4):

Facebook has 4 types of tokens: user, app, page and client (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens).  Each of these token types have their own permissions.  For example, you can post on behalf of a user (once they've granted you permission) using the app access token but need a user access token to pull user/statuses.  The web user access token are short-lived (~1-2 hrs) and need to be converted to a long-lived (60 days) access token.

In python you can extend the token server-side calling the GraphAPI extend_access_token method assuming you are using the facebook-sdk (pip install facebook-sdk).

views.py:

```
import facebook

user_access_token = 'USER_ACCESS_TOKEN' # initially generated client-side
app_id = 'YOUR_UNIQUE_APP_ID' # found at developer.facebook.com
app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET' # found at developer.facebook.com

# Create fb graph object
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(user_access_token)

# Now extend it with the extend_access_token method
extended_token = graph.extend_access_token(app_id=app_id, app_secret=app_secret)

# Confirm token now expires in ~ 60 days or 5184000 seconds
print extended_token
```

Now that the token is extended, you can store and use on the users behalf w/out an active web client.